# Populate dynamic dropdown menu in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a 'Course' model in my rails 5 app with a table defined as such:

```
class CreateCourse < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :department
        t.string :professor
    end
  end
end
```

I want to create a set of 3 dynamic drop down menus, with each dependent on the previous ones.

Example:

When users select the `department` in the first menu, it'll automatically filter and populate the second menu with the name of the records matching the selected `department`. After users have selected the `department` and the `name`, the 3rd menu should automatically be populated with the `professor` of the records that match those 2 criteria.

Is there a way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
              <% Project.all.each do |f| %>
                <%= link_to f.name,f %>
                <%= link_to f.department,f %>
                <%= link_to f.professor,f %>
              <% end %>
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: No, it's not. Im looking for a way to dynamically update dropdown menu's based on user's selection.The menu should update if the department or name selection has been changed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a client-side problem to me. If your client is a web browser, you'll wind up doing this in javascript. Add an event listener to the `change` event for each dropdown.